# Not able to access according to the condition

Tags: c

When I assign

```
 int r, s, t, u, v;
```

none of the if conditions are working. It may be because all the variables are assigned some garbage value.

When I assign

```
 int r=0, s=0, t=0, u=0, v=0;
```

All the if conditions are working. Is it because all of them are assigned a fixed value, and it is not changing?

Can anyone please tell me a method to run if conditions using the variables.

```
int r, s, t, u, v;
if((mouseXPos < 130 && mouseXPos > 30 && mouseYPos > 365 && mouseYPos < 410)&&(s==0)&&      (t==0)&&(u==0)&&(v==0))
    {
        drawMenu(0);
        r=1;
    }
if((mouseXPos < 230 && mouseXPos > 130 && mouseYPos > 365 && mouseYPos < 410)&&(r==0)&&(t==0)&&(u==0)&&(v==0))
    {
        drawMenu(1);
        s=1;
    }
if((mouseXPos < 330 && mouseXPos > 230 && mouseYPos > 365 && mouseYPos < 410)&&(r==0)&&(s==0)&&(u==0)&&(v==0))
    {
        drawMenu(2);
        t = 1;
    }
if((mouseXPos < 430 && mouseXPos > 330 && mouseYPos > 365 && mouseYPos < 410)&&(r==0)&&(s==0)&&(t==0)&&(v==0))
    {
        drawMenu(3);
        u = 1;
    }
if((mouseXPos < 530 && mouseXPos > 430 && mouseYPos > 365 && mouseYPos < 410)&&(r==0)&&(t==0)&&(u==0)&&(s==0))
    {
        drawMenu(4);
        v = 1;
    }
if(mouseXPos < 130 && mouseXPos > 30 && mouseYPos < 185 && mouseYPos > 140)
    {
        drawMenu(5);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way that you can compare a variable before initialising it with a particular value. If you do so you are actually comparing with garbage value stored in that variable.

In the first `if()` statement you are comparting s,t,u,v variables with some particular value. Before that s,t,u,v should have some value. You have just declared those variables and have not initialised them. As you have guessed correctly they will have some garbage value which may or may not be 0 ( most of the cases it is not 0) thats why those if conditions are not getting executed.

Comment: But if I initialize them as zero all the if conditions are getting executed. So, there is no point of condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare int if you don't pass them any values. That is correct if you declare int locally in function, but if you declare it outside functions (globally), they get value of 0, even if you don't pass them any values.

Answer (score 0):

The value of uninitialised variables without static storage class is undefined until they are explicitly assigned, but even when you have initialised them zero, they are not "fixed"; the variables are reassigned at various points in the code in your example.

For example first the condition tests `s`, `t`, `u` and `v` but modifies `r`, so if the first condition is met, in subsequent conditions r is 1, so all the following conditions will not be met.

It looks to be a rather convoluted method of executing one-and-only-one of the conditional blocks, since when any condition is matched, it sets a variable that prevents all others from matching.  If that is the intent however there are far simpler methods - it is equivalent for example to the much simpler:

```
int r = 0 ;
int s = 0 ;
int t = 0 ;
int u = 0 ;
int v = 0 ;

if ( mouseXPos < 130 && mouseXPos > 30 && 
     mouseYPos > 365 && mouseYPos < 410 )
{
    drawMenu(0);
    r=1;
}
else if( mouseXPos < 230 && mouseXPos > 130 && 
         mouseYPos > 365 && mouseYPos < 410)
{
    drawMenu(1);
    s=1;
}
else if( mouseXPos < 330 && mouseXPos > 230 && 
         mouseYPos > 365 && mouseYPos < 410)
{
    drawMenu(2);
    t = 1;
}
else if( mouseXPos < 430 && mouseXPos > 330 && 
         mouseYPos > 365 && mouseYPos < 410 )
{
    drawMenu(3);
    u = 1;
}
else if( mouseXPos < 530 && mouseXPos > 430 && 
         mouseYPos > 365 && mouseYPos < 410 )
{
    drawMenu(4);
    v = 1;
}
else if( mouseXPos < 130 && mouseXPos > 30 && 
         mouseYPos < 185 && mouseYPos > 140 )
{
    drawMenu(5);
}
```

In all this the setting of r, s, t, u, and v to 1 only makes any sense if they are used in subsequent code - otherwise they are entirely redundant and can be omitted.  Even id they are not redundant since either none or only one are ever set to 1, the same information can be represented by a single variable with a value 0 to 5 (i.e. exactly the same as the argument passed to `drawMenu()` in each condition.

It is hard to see any clear semantic sense to this code; which makes your attempt to understand it doubly difficult - you are trying to answer two questions; *how does it work?* and *what does it do?*.

In all but one condition however you are testing for the same mouseYpos condition unnecessarily - the code can be further simplified:

```
if( mouseYPos > 365 && mouseYPos < 410 )
{

    if ( mouseXPos < 130 && mouseXPos > 30 )
    {
        drawMenu(0);
    }
    else if( mouseXPos < 230 && mouseXPos > 130 ) 
    {
        drawMenu(1);
    }
    else if( mouseXPos < 330 && mouseXPos > 230 )
    {
        drawMenu(2);
    }
    else if( mouseXPos < 430 && mouseXPos > 330 )
    {
        drawMenu(3);
    }
    else if( mouseXPos < 530 && mouseXPos > 430 )
    {
        drawMenu(4);
    }
}
else if( mouseXPos < 130 && mouseXPos > 30 &&
         mouseYPos < 185 && mouseYPos > 140 )
{
    drawMenu(5);
}
```

And again this can be simplified further because if you have already tested for mouseXPos < 130 in one test, there is no need to check for >130 in the nect test - that is implicit (I am assuming that exactly equaly to 130 is not significant here and that you had in fact intended < 130 and >= 130:

```
if( mouseYPos > 365 && mouseYPos < 410 )
{

    if ( mouseXPos < 130 && mouseXPos > 30 )
    {
        drawMenu(0);
    }
    else if( mouseXPos < 230 ) 
    {
        drawMenu(1);
    }
    else if( mouseXPos < 330 )
    {
        drawMenu(2);
    }
    else if( mouseXPos < 430 )
    {
        drawMenu(3);
    }
    else if( mouseXPos < 530 )
    {
        drawMenu(4);
    }
}
else if( mouseXPos < 130 && mouseXPos > 30 &&
         mouseYPos < 185 && mouseYPos > 140 )
{
    drawMenu(5);
}
```

Furthermore you can exploit the arithmetic realtionship between the `drawMenu()` argument and the mouse position:

```
if( mouseYPos > 365 && mouseYPos < 410 )
{

    if( mouseXPos > 30 )
    {
        drawMenu( ((mouseXPos - 30) / 100) - 1 );
    }
}
else if( mouseXPos < 130 && mouseXPos > 30 &&
         mouseYPos < 185 && mouseYPos > 140 )
{
    drawMenu(5);
}
```